# How to retrieve the results of a VSTS query

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I have a query I can retrieve from the Azure Dev Ops api, as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

I can't see how to run this query to get the results:

Q: how do I run a query (by query ID) and get the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Run the query

You can get the id from the query:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#query_by_name

Then just run it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

2. Run the wiql from the query

Get the wiql property from the query:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#flat_query_with_expanded_clauses

Run that wiql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Ive tried this, but for some reason, I do not get a wiql in my get response. any examples to share?